# Weka command line attributes arguments

Tags: attributes, command, arguments, line, weka

On the command line, I'm able to get this rolling with no problem:

```
java weka.Run weka.classifiers.timeseries.WekaForecaster -W 
"weka.classifiers.functions.MultilayerPerceptron -L 0.01 -M 0.2 -N 500 -V 0 -S 0 -E 20 -H 20 " -t "C:\MyFile.arff" -F DirectionNumeric  -L 1 -M 3 -prime 3 -horizon 6 -holdout 100 -G TradeDay -dayofweek -weekend -future
```

But once I try to put the skip list, I start to get errors saying that it's missing a date that is not in the skip list even though the date is in fact on it:

java weka.Run weka.classifiers.timeseries.WekaForecaster -W "weka.classifiers.functions.MultilayerPerceptron -L 0.01 -M 0.2 -N 500 -V 0 -S 0 -E 20 -H 20 " -t "C:\MyFile.arff" -F DirectionNumeric  -L 1 -M 3 -prime 3 -horizon 6 -holdout 100 -G TradeDay -dayofweek -weekend -future -skip ""2014-06-07@yyyy-MM-dd, 2014-06-12"

Does anybody knows how to get this working? Weka is low on documentation as far as I know.

Thank's in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Forget it.  I got it, the problem was the 's' must be in capital letters:

-Skip

instead of

-skip.